# NSPredicateで余りを求める%を記述するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか

Tags: swift, ios, macos, swift3

以下の配列arrayから、４以上で、なおかつ2で割り切れる数字を取り出したいです。

```
let array:NSArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

例えば、以下のように余りを求める`%2`を記述するとエラーが出ます。

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF > 4 AND SELF%2 == 0")
array.filtered(using: predicate)
```

Comment: 最後の行の"arr.filtered"は、"array.filtered"の間違いです

Comment: 編集という機能がありますので間違いがありましたら編集をしていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

残念ながら`NSPredicate`の演算子には、剰余を求めるものは無いようです。(ちなみに`%`はフォーマット用のパラメータとみなされるので、不正な形式のフォーマットを指定するとエラー落ちします。)

[BNF Definition of Cocoa Predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001796-CJBDBHCB)

ただ英語ありで検索をかけるとこんな記事が出てきました。

[How to fetch even and odd values from core data using Predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36605430/6541007)

どうやらきちんと明記されたドキュメントは見当たりませんが、`NSExpression`での定義済み関数はどれも使えるようです。

(NSExpression.hより)※ちと長いので綺麗に桁合わせできていません。悪しからず。

> ```
> // Predefined functions are:
> // name              parameter array contents             returns
> //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> // sum:              NSExpression instances representing numbers      NSNumber 
> // count:            NSExpression instances representing numbers      NSNumber 
> // min:              NSExpression instances representing numbers      NSNumber  
> // max:              NSExpression instances representing numbers      NSNumber
> // average:          NSExpression instances representing numbers      NSNumber
> // median:           NSExpression instances representing numbers      NSNumber
> // mode:             NSExpression instances representing numbers      NSArray     (returned array will contain all occurrences of the mode)
> // stddev:           NSExpression instances representing numbers      NSNumber
> // add:to:           NSExpression instances representing numbers      NSNumber
> // from:subtract:    two NSExpression instances representing numbers  NSNumber
> // multiply:by:      two NSExpression instances representing numbers  NSNumber
> // divide:by:        two NSExpression instances representing numbers  NSNumber
> // modulus:by:       two NSExpression instances representing numbers  NSNumber
> // sqrt:             one NSExpression instance representing numbers       NSNumber
> // log:              one NSExpression instance representing a number  NSNumber
> // ln:               one NSExpression instance representing a number  NSNumber
> // raise:toPower:    one NSExpression instance representing a number  NSNumber
> // exp:              one NSExpression instance representing a number  NSNumber
> // floor:            one NSExpression instance representing a number  NSNumber
> // ceiling:          one NSExpression instance representing a number  NSNumber
> // abs:              one NSExpression instance representing a number  NSNumber
> // trunc:            one NSExpression instance representing a number  NSNumber
> // uppercase:        one NSExpression instance representing a string  NSString
> // lowercase:        one NSExpression instance representing a string  NSString
> // random            none                         NSNumber (integer) 
> // randomn:          one NSExpression instance representing a number  NSNumber (integer) such that 0 <= rand < param
> // now               none                         [NSDate now]
> // bitwiseAnd:with:  two NSExpression instances representing numbers  NSNumber    (numbers will be treated as NSInteger)
> // bitwiseOr:with:   two NSExpression instances representing numbers  NSNumber    (numbers will be treated as NSInteger)
> // bitwiseXor:with:  two NSExpression instances representing numbers  NSNumber    (numbers will be treated as NSInteger)
> // leftshift:by:     two NSExpression instances representing numbers  NSNumber    (numbers will be treated as NSInteger)
> // rightshift:by:    two NSExpression instances representing numbers  NSNumber    (numbers will be treated as NSInteger)
> // onesComplement:   one NSExpression instance representing a numbers NSNumber    (numbers will be treated as NSInteger)
> // noindex:          an NSExpression                  parameter   (used by CoreData to indicate that an index should be dropped)
> // distanceToLocation:fromLocation: two NSExpression instances representing CLLocations    NSNumber
> // length:           an NSExpression instance representing a string         NSNumber
> ```

※一部は`NSArray`には使えてもCore Data等のクエリーには使えない可能性があります。

```
let array: NSArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF > 4 AND modulus:by:(SELF,2) == 0")
array.filtered(using: predicate)
```

---

またCore Data等に使う必要が無いと言う前提なら、自前のメソッドを呼び出すこともできるようです。

```
extension NSNumber {
    @objc func isEven() -> NSNumber {
        return (self.intValue % 2 == 0) as NSNumber
    }
}

let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "SELF > 4 AND FUNCTION(SELF,'isEven')==1")
array.filtered(using: predicate2)
```

---

なお*配列から*と言うのを本当に大前提として良いのであれば、Swiftの`Array`の`filter`メソッドを使った方が簡単でしょう。

```
let arr: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

let result = arr.filter { $0 > 4 && $0 % 2 == 0 }
print(result) //->[6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: 複数の方法をご教授いただき非常に参考になりました。いただいた参考情報並びにNSExpressionについても勉強してみます、ありがとう！